# Web app: Can I download a PDF file, keep track of it, edit and upload it again?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, local-storage

I want to build a web app (in JavaScript) where the user can download a PDF file, edit it with a local application and upload it again.

I want to offer the user a list of downloaded files that s/he might want to upload again. My questions:

1. Can the app somehow keep track of the filename the PDF was downloaded to?
2. Can it check if the downloaded file was modified?
3. What about standards today and in the future for this?

I do not want to do the upload. The user should that. I just wonder if I can keep track of these things (and store that info to local storage) to make it easier for the user.

Well, I am also looking for how I can offer the user to upload the file, i.e. how can I suggest to the user to upload that particular file s/he has been editing?

**Note:** The question is rather similar to this, but it is not really the same question (since I just want to keep track of things): [Download file, open it locally, edit and then upload - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645836/download-file-open-it-locally-edit-and-then-upload)

Comment: You can serve up a PDF file that the user can download and edit... But you won't have any visibility as to where they saved it or what they saved it as.  They can then re-upload it but they'll have to locate the file themselves... And you can't    specify what folder to start looking in (though it typically defaults to the last used folder). Most of these restrictions are due to end user privacy/security.

Comment: Thanks @scunliffe. Yes, that is what I believe, but I am hoping I am wrong. Surely this is a common problem and things are evolving. ;-)